# Could not transfer artifact ... Authorization failed for .... 403 Forbidden - How to fix this error in InteliJ?

Tags: maven, bitbucket, maven-dependency

I am trying set a repository in InteliJ and while downloading the Maven dependency, getting the following error:

> Could not transfer artifact xyz.abc.pqr.abcdefgh:pom:15.5.5 from/to abcdefgh-maven-repository (https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/abcdefgh/maven_repository/src/releases): Authorization failed for https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/abcdefgh/maven_repository/src/releases/xyz/abc/pqr/qwert/abcdefgh/15.5.5/abcdefgh-15.5.5.pom 403 Forbidden

*changed the repo name

Comment: Questions about commercial products and their configuration

Comment: Can you do it from the command line...